# How to replicate rows of pandas upto x counts, where x is the difference of max count and the count of data for each category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame which has 2 columns- Query and Category. In the category column I have 121 unique categories. I need to replicate the rows of each category by x times where x is diiference between the maximum count a category has and the current count of each category, and store the result in a new data frame. Example: for the category alpha I have 5 different queries, I need to replicate this query for 319 times to make it equal to the max_count of 324. (i.e. 324-5 = 319). Code I have as of now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('Query_cat_121.csv')
print(len(df1['Category'].unique())
list_of_cats = []
for i in set(df['Category']):
    list_of_cats.append(i)

list_of_differences = []
print(df['Category'].value_counts().nlargest(1))
max_count = 797 //based on previous line
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
// want to append modified dataframe here
```

```
A Sample of the data frame I have:

Query    Category
apple    fruits
banana   fruits
mango    fruits
bat      animal
cat      animal
rat      animal
lion     animal
potato   veggie
```

```
A Sample of the data frame I want:

Query    Category
apple    fruits
banana   fruits
mango    fruits
apple    fruits
bat      animal
cat      animal
rat      animal
lion     animal
potato   veggie
potato   veggie
potato   veggie
potato   veggie
```

This is the output since I want all other categories to be replicated as many times as to reach the max count of a category which is 4 here.

Comment: please provide a clear input/output example

Comment: I think your question is missing some words. Maybe you have left out the word "difference"? Did you mean to say " I need to replicate the rows of each category C x times, where x is the DIFFERENCE BETWEEN the maximum count OF ANY category and the count of C ."

Comment: @Ujjwal can you share the minimal dataframe please

Comment: @Ujjwal so you just want the first row to copied if it becomes short right? also check answer and let us know if that helps

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar how is it only the first row, you can see for the category veggies I needed to replicate the rows 3 more times as max-veggie count = 4-1 = 3. Similarly for the category fruits, I needed to replicate it 1 just more time as max-fruit count = 4-3 = 1.

Comment: I means lets say if there are 4 max for a category, and one of the category has only 2 rows then which row should be replicated? first one or the second one

Comment: Also please try David's answer and let us know if that helps

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar in that case the first 2 need to be replicated and David's answer is throwing an error!

Comment: And in case of odd max values? say 7 max and 3 rows in one category, 3*2=6, what about the 7th data?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar repeat row 1 again, keep repeating until we reach max.

Comment: @UjjwalKarnani can you try my answer and let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Thanks alot again. Could you please explain the last line of your answer (that includes the lambda function)

Comment: `(lambda d: pd.concat(([d]*math.ceil(rep_val/d.shape[0]))).head(rep_val)).reset_index(drop=True)` it says concat the dataframe `d` that belongs to each group by repeating the same dataframe by rounding to upper limit of (`size of max group/ size of current group` but since that will create some extra row, so take only top(size of max group) values using `head`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.dataframe.groupby` and then replicate the data based on your logic and choose the max among them.

```
dict_ = {
    'Query' : ['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'bat', 'cat', 'rat', 'lion', 'potato', 'london', 'new jersey'],
    'Category': ['fruits', 'fruits', 'fruits', 'animal', 'animal', 'animal', 'animal', 'veggie', 'place', 'place'],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)

df
        Query Category
0       apple   fruits
1      banana   fruits
2       mango   fruits
3         bat   animal
4         cat   animal
5         rat   animal
6        lion   animal
7      potato   veggie
8      london    place
9  new jersey    place

rep_val= df.groupby('Category').size().max()
df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda d: pd.concat(([d]*math.ceil(rep_val/d.shape[0]))).head(rep_val)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

which gives us the expected output :

```
         Query Category
0          bat   animal
1          cat   animal
2          rat   animal
3         lion   animal
4        apple   fruits
5       banana   fruits
6        mango   fruits
7        apple   fruits
8       london    place
9   new jersey    place
10      london    place
11  new jersey    place
12      potato   veggie
13      potato   veggie
14      potato   veggie
15      potato   veggie
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you are asking, but I think you may be asking this:

*Given a dataframe D with columns `Query` and `Category`, I want to add X new copies of every row, where X depends on the value of `Category`. The value of X for category q = C_M - C_q, where C_M is the cardinality of the highest-count category and C_q is the cardinality of q in the data frame.*

A simple way to get started on this is:

```
difference_ser = df1['Category'].value_counts() - df1['Category'].value_counts().max()

difference_dict = difference_ser.to_dict()
```

And now you have a dictionary that tells you how many extra copies of each line to add.

Then you can use `repeat` to create new dataframes for each category.

```
my_dfs_to_add = []
for c in list(df1['Category'].unique()):
    tiling_df = df1[df1['Category'] = c]
    df_to_add = pd.Dataframe({
         'Query': tiling_df['Query'].repeat(difference_dict[c])
         'Category': tiling_df['Category'].repeat(difference_dict[c])
        }
     )
     my_dfs_to_add.append(df_to_add)
```

Then just concatenate all the dfs you made and append it to your original df.